# Link error with Rtools mingw_64 and Eigen

Tags: r, c++11, eigen, rcpp

We have a C++ library (libEDM.a) that integrates Eigen.  The library is standalone as a core API to be wrapped with Rcpp and pybind11 for user interfaces.

Since Eigen is called internally from the library, we do not use RcppEigen in the Rcpp wrapper.

This works fine on linux and OSX R package builds, and the mingw-32 (arch - i386) build for R (using devtools::check_win_release).

However, for the (arch - x64) build with mingw-64, the linker fails to find Eigen references in the C++ libEDM.a, vis (from winbuilder):

```
d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_64/bin/g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rEDMNew.dll tmp.def CCM.o ComputeError.o DataFrame.o Embed.o EmbedDim.o Multiview.o PredictInterval.o PredictNL.o RcppEDMCommon.o RcppExports.o SMap.o Simplex.o -L./cppEDM/src/ -lEDM -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LD:/RCompile/recent/R-3.6.1/bin/x64 -lR

./cppEDM/src//libEDM.a(SMap.o):SMap.cc:(.text+0x245d): undefined reference to `Eigen::internal::first_aligned_impl<16, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs2_op<double>, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false> const, -1, 1, false> const>, true>::run(Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs2_op<double>, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false> const, -1, 1, false> const> const&)'
```

A wrinkle for the mingw-64 is the addition of `-Wa,-mbig-obj` flag passed to the linker, as it seems Eigen templates with mingw-64 exceed the number of sections allowed.

Perhaps it is a mingw-64 linker/option issue, as the mingw-32 and other builds seem to work fine?

---

**Update**:
It seems that the linker configuration and Eigen are stuck in some kind of recursive search.  Using Rtools35 on a Windows 10 box with R 3.4.3, and the following Makevars.win:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I./cppEDM/src -I../
PKG_LIBS     = -L./cppEDM/src/ -lEDM
CXX_STD      = CXX11

$(SHLIB): cppEDM/src/libEDM.a

cppEDM/src/libEDM.a:
    @(cd cppEDM/src && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mingw \
          CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="-Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../ $(CPICFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)")
```

The build has two phases.  First the Rcpp interface code is compiled by the canonical Makefile, then the libEDM.a is built in cppEDM/src, which is then linked against the Rcpp objects for the final library.

The i386 build seems fine, creates and installs `rEDMNew.dll` as noted below.  The x64 build appears to build without incident, and then takes about 20 minutes to create `rEDMNew.dll` in the `src/-x64/` directory.  However, it then seems stalled, CPU running ~50% for hours... and the `rEDMNew.dll` not installed.

Any ideas?  Perhaps a linker flag?

I presume that x64 build failure is a CRAN disqualification.  This is the last hurdle, but seems like a big one.

```
C:.\EDM\rEDM_cpp_dev>R CMD INSTALL rEDMNew

In R CMD INSTALL
* installing to library './R/win-library/3.4'
* installing *source* package 'rEDMNew' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386

c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c CCM.cpp -o CCM.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c ComputeError.cpp -o ComputeError.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c DataFrame.cpp -o DataFrame.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Embed.cpp -o Embed.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c EmbedDim.cpp -o EmbedDim.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Multiview.cpp -o Multiview.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c PredictInterval.cpp -o PredictInterval.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c PredictNL.cpp -o PredictNL.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppEDMCommon.cpp -o RcppEDMCommon.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c SMap.cpp -o SMap.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Simplex.cpp -o Simplex.o

make[1]: Entering directory './src-i386/cppEDM/src'

c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Common.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c AuxFunc.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c DateTimeUtil.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Parameter.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Embed.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Interface.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Neighbors.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Simplex.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Eval.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c CCM.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c Multiview.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -c SMap.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/ar -rcs libEDM.a Common.o AuxFunc.o DateTimeUtil.o Parameter.o Embed.o Interface.o Neighbors.o Simplex.o Eval.o CCM.o Multiview.o SMap.o
cp libEDM.a ../lib/

make[1]: Leaving directory './src-i386/cppEDM/src'

c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rEDMNew.dll tmp.def CCM.o ComputeError.o DataFrame.o Embed.o EmbedDim.o Multiview.o PredictInterval.o Pred
ictNL.o RcppEDMCommon.o RcppExports.o SMap.o Simplex.o -L./cppEDM/src/ -lEDM -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/i386 -lR

installing to ./R/win-library/3.4/rEDMNew/libs/i386


*** arch - x64

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c CCM.cpp -o CCM.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c ComputeError.cpp -o ComputeError.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c DataFrame.cpp -o DataFrame.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Embed.cpp -o Embed.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c EmbedDim.cpp -o EmbedDim.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Multiview.cpp -o Multiview.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c PredictInterval.cpp -o PredictInterval.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c PredictNL.cpp -o PredictNL.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppEDMCommon.cpp -o RcppEDMCommon.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c SMap.cpp -o SMap.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cppEDM/src -I../ -I"./R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c Simplex.cpp -o Simplex.o

make[1]: Entering directory './src-x64/cppEDM/src'

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Common.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c AuxFunc.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c DateTimeUtil.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Parameter.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Embed.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Interface.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Neighbors.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Simplex.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Eval.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c CCM.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c Multiview.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -c SMap.cc -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++11 -DCCM_THREADED -DMULTIVIEW_VALUES_OVERLOAD -I../
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/ar -rcs libEDM.a Common.o AuxFunc.o DateTimeUtil.o Parameter.o Embed.o Interface.o Neighbors.o Simplex.o Eval.o CCM.o Multiview.o SMap.o
cp libEDM.a ../lib/

make[1]: Leaving directory './src-x64/cppEDM/src'

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rEDMNew.dll tmp.def CCM.o ComputeError.o DataFrame.o Embed.o EmbedDim.o Multiview.o PredictInterval.o Pred
ictNL.o RcppEDMCommon.o RcppExports.o SMap.o Simplex.o -L./cppEDM/src/ -lEDM -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64 -lR
```

-- This is where it just grinds away...

Apologies if I've transgressed a social norm by editing this post.  Seemed like a logical thing to do rather than starting a new one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not an Rcpp or RcppEigen issue, as you say, as RcppEigen only requires the header files.  This comes from the other part of your project.

Comment: And how to build a package with R (or Rcpp) that requires an external library is also explained in a few places.  But you cannot assume the Eigen library to be present on eg CRAN so you need to work out how to do things.  We can help, but it involves a few steps.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  Agreed: it's not an Rcpp issue per-se, as it works just fine on all but mingw-64 (arch - x64) build.  So it seems a link configuration issue.  Problem is: I don't know how to make progress...  btw: Congrats on Rcpp. it is a phenomenal contribution.  Many thanks...